# AS3 postgresql and amfphp for facebook/heroku?

Tags: php, facebook, flash, postgresql, heroku

My goal was to turn a flash game I created into a facebook app and add a leaderboard to the game that would encourage some competition.

So far I have installed the app on Facebook with Heroku, set up the dev postgresql on Heroku and created a table and inserted some sample data with psql.  I am able to retrieve the user's data with the facebook api.  Using Amfphp I was able to communicate with php in my app, but I have a hit a wall with reading/writing the database.  Probably cause I'm weaksauce with php.

I guess I'm wondering if anybody knows if amfphp works ok with postgresql or if there's a preferred practice for what I'm trying to do. Any tutorials or tips would be great.

This is the closest I've come so far which returns an `[Object object]` in flash that I can't figure out how to do anything with:

```
public function registerNoob($id){
     $dsn = "pgsql:"
     . "host=ec2-107-22-161-45.compute-1.amazonaws.com;"
     . "dbname=dbvgstj2v06pit;"
     . "user=jytgyzybpoqjed;"
     . "port=5432;"
     . "sslmode=require;"
     . "password=obscured";
     $db = new PDO($dsn);

     $query = "SELECT * FROM noobs WHERE fbID = '$id';";
     $result = $db->query($query);
     return $result;
}
```

Comment: I don't really see where the question here is. http://stackoverflow.com/faq specifically http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: My question is how do you read/write to the postgresql db using flash and php?

Comment: That's probably going to prove to be too general for this site (as per the FAQ) so be warned that it might get closed.

Answer (score 1):

first some tips on Flash/PHP:

1. write some PHP that does what you want to do.
2. try wrapping this in an amfPHP service.
3. Try calling it from the service browser.
4. Then and only then try calling this from Flash.

amfPHP really doesn't care about which DB you use.

Look at the PDO PHP library, it should help you.

Right now you are returning a "resource", that Flash doesn't know what to do with, you should convert this to an array of some sort before returing it to Flash. PDO helps with this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I got it working by putting the data in an array and returning that to flash or at least thought I did but currently only 13/26 people who have approved my app have been saved in my db. I don't know how to reproduce the issue, it works every time for me. Makes me very sad.